# UITableView move to the top when pushing

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

I am using `UITableViewController` to display data, which is embedded into a custom container, but the problem is when I try to push another view controller and pop it again I notice that the `UITableView` was moved to the top. Is there any solution so I can fix it?

You can see the bug Here:

**Before Pushing**

[image]

**After Pushing and Popping**

[image]

Comment: Provide some code. That will help people to solve your problem.

Comment: There isn't anycode, all the manipulations is from storyboard

Comment: Then give more details with respect to the image like which is the custom conatainer, which is the table view. What exactly is the bug etc..

Comment: Your screenshots do not do a proper representation of the problem you're having.